# Degree distribution command in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

Just a simple question. Let k(i) be the degree of node i in an undirected network. Is there a defined command like "DegreeCentrality" to plot the degree distribution (plotting P(k) versus k) of a graph like

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "ZacharyKarateClub"}]
```

or do I have to write the code?

Comment: Like `Histogram`? `Histogram[DegreeCentrality[g], {1}, "Probability"]`?

Comment: Thank you. I just wrote: `data = VertexDegree[g] // Tally`,
`data2 = Table[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]]/VertexCount[g]}, {i, 
    data // Length}] // Sort`,
`plot1 = ListPlot[data2]` and `plot2 = Histogram[DegreeCentrality[g], {1}, "Probability"]` which is yours. And they overlap well. Mine was ListPlot and yours was Histogram. You showed me the short way. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. If you want to make your own plot using the same underlying data as `Histogram` you can look at [`HistogramList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramList.html).

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the code.

```
Histogram[VertexDegree[g], {1}, "Probability", 
 AxesLabel -> {"degree", "probability"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, it is simple enough that there is little reason to have a command for it.

Comment: Thank you. I think there is a difference between Mathematica 10 and 11. I am using 10 and same code gave me a shifted version of this histogram. I mean first yellow bar is between points (horizontal) 1 and 2, second bar (the long one) is between 2 and 3 etc.

Comment: @Haliki You could use a more precise bin specification (2nd argument of `Histogram`), such as `{-1/2, Max@VertexDegree[g] + 1/2, 1}`.  It seems that there are differences between various versions in how they determine the bins in automatic mode.  BTW you can consider x.y to be a major version. 10.3 and 10.4 may have differences as big as 10.4 and 11.0.

Comment: @Haliki Shameless advertisement: if you work with graphs frequently, you may want to check out [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM). I am looking for feedback in preparation for a new release. Contributions to the documentation would also be very welcome.

Comment: It worked thank you very much. I'll download and investigate the package.